# npm install error: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Trying to install express or any other package with npm brings forth this error
"npm ERR! Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined"

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

npm@8.5.1

node@v12.22

#### Sections of debug log

0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'express' ]
1 info using npm@8.5.1

2 info using node@v12.22.9

23 verbose logfile /home/kiama/.npm/_logs/2022-04-25T18_29_12_505Z-debug-0.log

24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 12ms

25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms

26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms

27 timing npm:load Completed in 73ms

28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 2ms

29 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files

34 silly fetch manifest express@*

35 silly placeDep ROOT express@ OK for: server@1.0.0 want: *

36 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 458ms

37 timing idealTree:node_modules/express Completed in 1ms

38 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 462ms

39 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms

40 timing idealTree Completed in 513ms

41 timing command:install Completed in 579ms

42 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined

42 verbose stack     at CacheEntry.store (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/entry.js:325:27)

42 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js:18:18)

44 verbose Linux 5.15.0-25-generic

45 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "express"

46 verbose node v12.22.9

47 verbose npm  v8.5.1

48 error Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the Node.js version (rather old) and the npm version (rather new).